Definition multiplication Dedekind cuts concerning union with r<0 elements of Q
I'm studying the definition of Dedekind cuts and I think I have a decent grasp except I'm held up on how multiplication is defined. I've scoured a handful of textbooks (Pugh, Abbot, Rudin, Royden) and as expected keeping finding equivalent definitions that don't solve my issue.
Every definition of multiplication of two positive numbers accurately includes the elements of $\mathbf{Q}$ less than 0. Authors then go on to define multiplication of $x$ and $y$ with various signs by converting $x$ and $y$ to positives then negating the result as applicable. Pugh's definition of cut multiplication
HOWEVER, how can all numbers less than 0 be included in cuts $x \cdot y$ where $x$ xor $y$ is negative?
If the resulting product $x \cdot y = E|F$ where $x=A|B$ and $y=C|D$ is negative, shouldn't
$$E=\{r\in \mathbf{Q} : r\leq 0 \ \mathrm{or} \ \exists \ a \in A \ \mathrm{and} \ \exists \ c  \in C  \ \mathrm{such \ that} \ a>0, c>0,\mathrm{and} \ r=ac \}$$
be redefined using "and" and/or changing the relation of $a$ and/or $c$ and 0?
$$E=\{r\in \mathbf{Q} : r\leq 0 \ \mathbf{and} \ \exists \ a \in A \ \mathrm{and} \ \exists \ c  \in C  \ \mathrm{such \ that} \ a\ ?\ 0, c\ ?\ 0,\mathrm{and} \ r=ac \}$$
I've got to be overlooking something in the logic of converting $x$ and $y$ to positives then negating the result? Or is it assumed that the definition has to change slightly to handle each sign case?
An example I tried to work out. What is my error?

Such notation as you have introduced is not really suitable to discuss the advantages of defining the product of two positive Dedekind cuts first and the collateral definitions for other cases (nonpositive).  Of course the  zero case is easy.  The use of $\mathbf Q$ here is a bit confusing.   For the rational numbers we typically use $\mathbb Q$.  In any case you probably need notation for the collection of Dedekind cuts, unless you are wanting to beg the question and just refer to them as the real number system $\mathbb R$.

@hardmath This notation is straight from a real analysis textbook, also it is my understanding that the notational custom is shifting away from \mathbb and towards \mathbf - that is what many of my recent textbooks and professors are using (Pugh uses bb, I’m in the habit of using bf). Regardless, by $\mathbf{Q}$ I mean to communicate $\mathbb{Q}$. Pugh initially defined the collection of all cuts as $\mathbf{R}$. Can you suggest a notation (or reference) for cut products that you think does show such advantages? I agree that this notation is murky hence my reason for posting this question.

I'm fine with saying $\mathbf Q$ is the rational numbers, and we need to talk about Dedekind cuts as  non-empty downward closed subsets of $\mathbf Q$.  Defining addition is easily done without resorting to cases, but multiplication benefits from doing the positive cuts first.  That case is the most straightforward construction.

@hardmath Thanks for your reply. Indeed,  I have a good grasp on addition of cuts, and I'm pretty sure I have the intuition for cuts as pairs of subsets of the rationals (A,B) where A has no largest element and their union equals the rationals. It's the nuance of defining each case of multiplication that is stumping me. I can get behind multiplication of positive cuts, but when one or more of the cuts are negative I'm getting lost in the notation (no matter which textbook I consult).
